# Javascript bot issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

So, I am trying to have a bit of fun with some annoying friends on facebook, and I decided to set up something to annoy them back:

```
var img = "http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article390636.ece/alternates/s2197/susan-    boyle-638865512.jpg";

setInterval(function() {

    var element = document.getElementById("TargetAttackArea");

    element.innerHTML = img;

}, 10);
```

It is supposed to insert the address in the variable "img" to the element's innerHTML as it is a  element. The code is returning a value when I paste it into the console, but it is not giving an error or doing what I intend it to do. Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: Do you want to assign the above `URL` to an `image` Element?

Comment: The URL was being pasted inside of a TextArea

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IBKjF)?

Comment: Well, how would this "annoy your friends back" on Facebook? You can't insert JS into FB...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to render an image and here `innerHTML` will just insert the string as HTML into the element targeted which would not do much but display the URL.

This would instead insert an image. Or you could simply target an image element and replace its `src` value.

```
setInterval(function() {

   var element = document.getElementById("TargetAttackArea");
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = img;

   element.appendChild(image);


}, 10);
```

However the `interval` is set to `10` in your code, those are milliseconds and unless you stop that interval soon after I doubt the browser will handle well having an image inserted every 10 milliseconds... You'll probably end annoying yourself too testing it!

Good read about `setInterval` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval